# Ошибка сборки проекта GTK+

Tags: c, codeblocks, gtk3

OS windows 10, Code::Blocks 17.12, GTK+ -> msys2-x86_64-20161025.exe

```
1-Создаю проект по шаблону GTK+
2-Компиляция проходит успешно
3-Сборка выдает ошибки:
||=== Сборка: Debug in g2 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `helloWorld':|
C:\Work\g2\main.c|8|undefined reference to `gtk_window_get_type'|
C:\Work\g2\main.c|8|undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'|
C:\Work\g2\main.c|8|undefined reference to `gtk_message_dialog_new'|
......................
C:\Work\g2\main.c|46|undefined reference to `gtk_widget_show_all'|
C:\Work\g2\main.c|47|undefined reference to `gtk_main'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build неудачно: 47 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0  second(s)) ===|
```

Предполагаю не соответствие шаблона C::B и установленного gtk+. Перепробовал различные виды конфигурации, но моих пониманий явно не достаточно.
Помогите разобраться и создать минимальный шаблон с подключеным файлом .glade

Что то подобное:

```
#include<gtk/gtk.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    GtkBuilder *gtkBuilder;
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    gtkBuilder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(gtkBuilder, "testGlade.glade", NULL);
    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(gtkBuilder, "mywindow"));

    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(gtkBuilder));
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: смотри флаги линковки... нужно добавить `-lgtk -lglib` итд, а также, вероятно, `-L/path/to/libs`... где именно они прописываются в Blocks'ах и как именно узнать полный список на win (на nix'ах делается с помощью `pkg-config`) — не подскажу...

Comment: Если наступит полное отчаянье и, если есть знакомый люних, выполните там команду: *pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0* и полученный список библиотек запишите за флажком -l для вашей сборки.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно линковаться к gtk3 - в GNU/Linux для этого используется команда `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0`, результат выполнения которой передаётся компилятору. Судя по всему, у Вас используется MinGW - установите pkg-config и настройте codeblocks на его использование.

Comment: Выполнил команду конфигурации компиляции `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0`  и  команду конфигурации линковки `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`. Создал проект простого окна GTK3

Comment: ||=== Сборка: Debug in gtk1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
ld.exe||cannot find -ldwmapi|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build неудачно: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|